# Writing an attribute trait

Tags: raku, mop

I'm about to choose what language to use for a new project: Perl5 or Perl6. 6 wins so far except that it is missing `Moo`'s lazy attributes. The two implementations I found in modules are missing the key functionality. Hence, my attempt write my own implementation.

#### Role vs. Class

First problem I've got into is the content of attribute's `.package` for one declared in a role. Consider the followin:

```
 role HOW1 {
     method compose ( Mu $class ) {
         note "HOW1.compose";
         nextsame;
     }
 }

 role HOW2 {
     method compose ( Mu $class ) {
         note "HOW2.compose";
         nextsame;
     }
 }

 multi trait_mod:<is> (Attribute:D $attr, :$mooish!) {
     note "Attribute's package.HOW: ", $attr.package.HOW;
     note '$*PACKAGE.HOW: ', $*PACKAGE.HOW;
     $attr.package.HOW does HOW1;
     $*PACKAGE.HOW does HOW2;
 }

 class Foo {
     has $.bar is mooish;
 }

 role FooRole {
     has $.baz is mooish;
 }
```

The output of the script follows:

```
Attribute's package.HOW: Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW.new
$*PACKAGE.HOW: Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW.new
HOW2.compose
HOW1.compose
Attribute's package.HOW: Perl6::Metamodel::GenericHOW.new
$*PACKAGE.HOW: Perl6::Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW.new
HOW2.compose
```

As it is clearly seen from the output, applying a role to a metaclass always works for classes and only works for `$*PACKAGE.HOW` with roles. Use of `$*PACKAGE` instead of `.package` could be considered a solution, but not the one I'd really like to use. (*Though, if there is no better way...*)

#### Accessor

I would like to provide lazy functionality for private attributes too. Yes, this will be availabe with `self!bar` syntax only, but *this is a sacrifice I'm willing to make*.  The problem is that all the examples of custome-made accessor I found so far are using `Attribute.set_value()` method which is way too low-level. I'd like to have something like this:

```
 role MooishHOW {
     method compose ( Mu $class ) {
         my $accessor = $class.^add_private_method( 'bar1',
             method () is rw {
                 note self.WHO, ".bar1";
                 Proxy.new(
                     FETCH => -> $o {
                         $!bar1;
                     },
                     STORE => method ( $val ) {
                         note "Storing";
                         $!bar1 = $val;
                     }
                 );
             }
         );

         callsame;
     }
 }

 multi trait_mod:<is> (Attribute:D $attr, :$mooish!) {
     $attr.package.HOW does MooishHOW unless $attr.package.HOW ~~ MooishHOW;
 }

 class Foo {
     has $.bar is mooish;
     has $!bar1 is mooish;

     method to-bar1 {
         note "bar1 val:",self!bar1;
     }
 }

 my $inst = Foo.new;
 $inst.to-bar1;
```

But `$!bar1` notation doesn't compile because of the scope (`MooishRole`). Are there a trick I'm missing which would allow referencing a private attribute on `self`?

#### Tricky one

Perhaps it is possible to make an attribute to be a `Proxy` container? This would greatly simplify the overall logic of laziness implementation.

Comment: FWIW, I've been looking at getting the functionality of [Object::Trampoline](http://modules.perl6.org/dist/Object::Trampoline:cpan:ELIZABETH) into an attribute trait.  First attempts were not immediately successful :-(

Comment: Re: using a `Proxy`: `class A { has $!a; method a() is raw { Proxy.new } }` should do the trick?

Comment: Your trick still requires an accessor method. What I hoped for is to be able to intercept a `$!b`. Should be possible if `$!b` is a `Proxy`, but the question is how to make it this way. Though this is minor wish of mine, totally ignorable.

What I'm trying to get through now is to allow `Nil` parameter for the following:
`sub genp (::T $) { Proxy.new( STORE => method (T $v) {...} ) }`. It currently dies on storing a `Nil` becuase of type mismatch when `sub genp(Int) = Nil` (sure, `Nil ~~ Int` is falsy).

Comment: I'm currently occupied with adapting set operators as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580534/does-baggy-add-work-on-mixhash-weights , will look at this after that (probably later today)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have answered all my questions by finally achieving the target and released [AttrX::Mooish](http://modules.perl6.org/dist/AttrX::Mooish:cpan:VRURG) module.

So far, the answer for the first question is: no. `$*PACKAGE` is currently the only way.

Second question: have no answer, but the final code has to rely on `set_value()` anyway.

The tricky one happened to be possible: `set_value()` does binding of an attribue to a container making it possible to bind to a `Proxy` object. No need to for sacrifices, private attributes can be accessed directly with lazyness working on them.

Thanks everybody, your answers let me work around some rough edges!