# Declare and initialize a typed array from a range

Tags: arrays, range, raku, typing

I recently tried `my Array @a = 'a'..'z';` and `my Array @a = @('a'..'z');`.

Both will produce the following error:

```
Type check failed in assignment to @a; expected Array but got Str ("a")
in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

However initializing without the type works and seems to ultimately produce an Array:

```
> my @a = 'a'..'z';
> @a.^name
Array
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: I guess when you are typing an array, the type applies to each element in the array. So in your case the type of each element is not `Array` but `Str`. That's why you get the error `expected Array but got Str` when you type `@a` as `my Array @a`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR** I provide a relatively simple answer in **Why is this the case?** However, that explanation may be inadequate<sup>1</sup> so I review some alternatives in **Declare and initialize a typed array from a range.**

> Why is this the case?

- `my @a;` declares a new [`Array`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Array) (initialized to be empty) and "binds" it to the symbol `@a`. Thus `my @a; say @a.^name` returns `Array`. There is no need to use the word `Array` in a declaration or initialization of an array -- the `@` is enough.<sup>2</sup>
- `my @a = 'a'..'z'` attempts to *copy* each value in the range `'a'` thru `'z'`, one at a time, *into* `@a[0]`, `@a[1]`, etc. The new array bound to `@a` has a type constraint for each of its elements (explained in the next section); it will be checked for each value (and will succeed).
- `my Array @a` declares an `Array` with an `Array` type constraint on its elements (so it's an array of arrays). `my Array @a; say @a.^name` returns `Array[Array]` to indicate this. `my Array @a = 'a'..'z';` fails when copying the first value ("a") because it is a `Str` value not an `Array`.

> Declare and initialize a typed array from a range

```
my @a = 'a'..'z';
```

The `my @a` part of this statement declares a variable that's bound to (refers to) a new array of type [`Array`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Array). Because no element type constraint was specified, the new array's elements are constrained to be consistent with [`Mu`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mu), the **M**ost **u**nassuming type in P6. In other words it's an empty array ready to contain whatever values you want to put in it. (One could say that `say @a.^name` displays `Array` rather than `Array[Mu]` because the `[Mu]` is considered **M**ost **u**ninteresting.)

`... = 'a'..'z'` initializes the new array. The initialization has no impact on the array's already established type constraints. It just delivers copies of the strings `'a'`, `'b'` etc. *into* the array (which auto-expands to receive them into `@a[0]`, `@a[1]` etc.).

I recommend devs avoid adding explicit type constraints on variables and explicit coercions of values unless they're confident they're desirable. (cf my parenthetical remarks at the end of [an earlier SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51581427/1077672).) That said, you can choose to do so:

```
my Str @a = 'a'..'z';      # `Array` elements constrained to `Str`
my Str @a = (0..99)>>.Str; # Coerce value to match constraint
```

Alternatively, P6 supports explicit **binding**, rather than **assignment**, of a value or list of values. The most common way to do this is to use `:=` instead of `=`:

```
my @a := 'a'..'z'; say @a.WHAT; say @a[25]; # (Range)␤z
```

Note how the explicit binding of `@a` means `@a` has *not* been bound to a new `Array` but instead to the `Range` value. And because a `Range` can behave as a `Positional`, positional subscripting still works.

The following statements would imo be grossly redundant explicit typing but would both work and yield exactly the same outcome as each other, though the first one would be faster:

```
my Str @a := Array[Str].new('a'..'z'); 
my Str @a  = Array[Str].new('a'..'z');
```

There's more to discuss about this topic but perhaps the foregoing provides enough for this question/answer. If not, please ask further questions in comments under your original question and/or below.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> An earlier version of this answer began with:

```
my Array @a ...
# My array of thoughts raised by this declaration
# and your questing "why?" in this SO question
# began with wry thoughts about complicated answers
# about reasons your array is awry and pedances
```

(I made up the word "pedances" to mean something that *appears* to be pedantic but flows nicely when used correctly -- which will happen naturally once you've become familiar with its apparently idiosyncratic but actually helpful nature. More importantly, I needed something that rhymes with "answers".)

<sup>2</sup> Here are a couple of mnemonics for the meaning of `@` in P6:

- It *looks like* a zero digit (`0`) with an  ([Mathematical Italic Small A](https://unicode-table.com/en/1D44E/)) inside it -- and a `@foo` variable is by default a `0` indexed  (or `@`).
- It *sounds like* the word "at". An array has elements *at* indices.

Answer (score 7):

Set the type of the element in the array:

```
my Str @a = 'a'..'z'; 
say @a; #[a b c d e f g
```

To see, what type it is, you can use .WHAT

```
my Str @a = 'a'..'z'; 
say @a.WHAT #(Array[Str])
```

To test if it is an array, you can smartmatch

```
my Str @a = 'a'..'z'; 
say 'is array' if @a ~~ Array; #is array

say 'is str array' if @a ~~ Array[Str]; #is str array

say 'is str array' if @a ~~ Array[Int]; #
```

Answer (score 7):

The `@('a'..'z')` will make a `List` not an `Array`. Changing it to
`['a'..'z']` will give an `Array`.

But that will still give you a type error when assigning it to `my Array @a` as you have done.

If you want to assign an entire Array to an element of another array, you have to itemise it somehow eg:

```
$[1,2,3]; #Still an array but treated as single item
[1,2,3], ; #Note the list operator (comma), this give you a list of lists
```

So in your case:

`'a'..'z';`  is a range, needs to be converted to an array, so

`['a'..'z'];` range is now evaluated into an array

`$['a'..'z'];` range is now evaluated into an array and taken as a single item

```
my Array @a=$['a'..'z'];

say @a;

#OUTPUT:
#[[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z]]
# Which is an array of arrays;
```

Not sure if it is what you are after but it removes the type error.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array, you can easily specify what type the elements of the array are.

```perl6
my Str @a = 'a'..'z';
```

You can specify the exact class that is used for the storage as well.
The following line is exactly the same as the above line; since `Array` is the default storage class.

```perl6
my @a is Array[Str] = 'a'..'z';
```

You can even combine the two.
This following is also exactly the same.

```perl6
my Str @a is Array = 'a'..'z';
```

---

When you wrote the following line.

```perl6
my Array @a = 'a'..'z';
```

What you were actually saying was:

```perl6
my @a is Array[Array] = 'a'..'z';
```

I assume you thought you were writing this.

```perl6
my @a is Array = 'a'..'z';
```

---

This can be useful if you don't want the elements to change.

```perl6
my @a is List = 'a'..'z';
```

Or if you have specific needs that aren't satisfied by the default `Array` class.

```perl6
use Array::Unique; # doesn't really exist yet (afaik)

my @a is Array::Unique[Str] = 'a'..'z';

my Str @b is Array::Unique  = 'a'..'z';
```